# Merge [docker-swarm-mode] into [docker-swarm]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The [docker-swarm-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-swarm-mode) and [docker-swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-swarm) mode seem to describe the exact same thing. Here are the two descriptions:

[docker-swarm-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-swarm-mode)

> Swarm mode refers to cluster management and orchestration features embedded in Docker Engine. When you initialize a new swarm (cluster) or join nodes to a swarm, the Docker Engine runs in swarm mode.

[docker-swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-swarm)

> Docker Swarm is native clustering for Docker. It turns a pool of Docker hosts into a single, virtual host.

I suggest merging these two into [docker-swarm] as it has more questions.

Comment: It is not sufficient to just read the excerpts. You also need to look at how the tags are *actually* being used on questions. If you have subject-matter expertise, then we really need you to do this, because someone like me who barely knows what Docker is cannot make the assessment whether the tags are being used identically in the "real world". If it can be confirmed that they are *actually* being used identically, then this is a simple, straightforward case that can be handled with a one-click merge. Otherwise, there needs to be more work done to disambiguate them.

Comment: The tag [tag:docker-swarm-mode] has 286 questions of which 205 are also tagged with [tag:docker-swarm]. In the rest with only [tag:docker-swarm-mode] the tag seems to be used exactly the same as [tag:docker-swarm]